# Can't Set variable value in Static Field

Tags: c#, static, call

In this simple example Why `StrA` in `Sample()` function Can't set with "Hi World" string ?

```
string StrA { get; set; }

private void button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StrA = "Hi World";   //=======>   Get StrA value
}


public static string Sample()
{
    MyClass MyClass1 = new MyClass();

    string a = MyClass1.StrA;  //==========> Can't Set StrA value with "Hi World" string ???

    return (MessageBox.Show(a).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you post the classes you have? Is all of this code inside the `MyClass` class?

Comment: MyClass just Also included another event button function for call Sample().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make StrA a static field, right now it's just a local property of the instance, so when you create a new instance with
     MyClass1 = new MyClass();

the StrA property is empty (null) and even if you set it a value, after you create a new instance that new instance will have SrtA as empty...

Comment: ahaa! I get now why SrtA as empty tnx but if I dont create a new instance I get this error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication3.MyClass.StrA.get'

Comment: try making it `static string StrA { get; set; }` and every time you use it, use it as a static member : `MyClass.StrA` (not myclass1 but the name of the class)